# Manipulating variables in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

To create points with names P1, P2, ..., P8 at coordinates (1,0), (2,0), ..., (8,0) in TikZ, I can use

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]

  \foreach \i in {1,...,8}
  {
    \path (\i,0) coordinate (P\i);
    \fill (P\i) circle (2pt);
  }

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Now, what if I want to create the same eight points, but name them P2, P3, ..., P9 instead?

I've tried changing it to

```
\path (\i,0) coordinate (P(\i+1));
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Welcome to the [TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) and thank you for your question. Could you please extend your example to make it minimum working example, starting with `\documentclass...` and ending with `...\end{document}`. It helps solvers a lot to actually start solving the problem. It would be also great if you could change your display name from userxxx to something more descriptive, we are all human beings, right? `:-)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would work. Use an additional variable \t that relates, via a formula, to \i, as shown below. Here a node is added to print the label for visual expression.

```
[evaluate=\i as \t using int(\i+1)]
```

More: proposed by percusse, via

```
[count=\t from 2]
```

which means start counting from 2,3,4,...

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

Before:
\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]

  \foreach \i in {1,...,8}
  {
    \path (\i,0) coordinate (P\i) node[above]{P\i};
    \fill (P\i) circle (2pt);
  }

\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip
After:
\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]

  \foreach \i[evaluate=\i as \t using int(\i+1)] in {1,...,8}
  {
    \draw (\i,0) coordinate (P\t) node[above]{P\t};
    \fill (P\t) circle (2pt);
  }

\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip
More: proposed by percusse. 
\bigskip    

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]

  \foreach \i[count=\t from 2] in {1,...,8}
  {
    \draw (\i,0) coordinate (P\t) node[above]{P\t};
    \fill (P\t) circle (2pt);
  }

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe also including the possibility of `[count=\xi from 2]` ?

Comment: Hi, @percusse -- Great tips and allow me to quote your name to express my appreciation.

Comment: Oh please, it's my pleasure

Comment: @Jesse I tried copying your example exactly and get `Runaway argument?
int(\i +1)] in {1,...,8} { \draw (\i ,0) coordinate (P\t ) node[above\ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \pgffor@next was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.30 
     
? 
! Use of \i doesn't match its definition.
<argument> \i ,
               0
l.43   }
        
? 

! Package pgf Error: No shape named 0 is known.

See the pgf package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.`

Comment: @boaten I just did that copy and paste to run. It is fine. Please try again and I will check again.

Comment: @Jesse Ok I tried it on another machine and it's fine. Maybe it's due to some TeX installation issue... thanks anyway!